# How to install debian package into Python virtual environment: not in piwheels or pypi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I want to use an open source py file in a project.  This py file requires python3-usb and python3-setuptools niether of which are on pypi or piwheels.  I get the following error when running a pip3 command in both cases:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-usb (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for python3-usb
```

I have upgrade pip, my virtual envoronment is 3.9.2 and both pip and venv 'point' to venv/bin/python.  The python3-usb package does not exist in piwheel or pypi (I haven't checked python3-setuptools).  python3-usb  exists in the debian package list [python3-usb](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/python3-usb)

Is it possible to install this package using pip3 ?  Or failing that is there an alternative way of installing in the virtual environment ?

Thank you

Comment: As others have said, python3-usb is the debian name for the apt package.  The python project is called pyusb. However, from experience I can say that if you are avoiding sudo/apt (e.g. perhaps you are on a system with limited privilages) you may find that without some root configuration you won't be able to make the system settings which allow user access to drivers for USB ports. (You need to mess with /etc/udev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian has very strict [naming conventions](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/index.html#module-package-names) for their package names and thus tends to rename a lot of packages. The original name for python3-usb is [pyusb](https://pypi.org/project/pyusb/), which is on pypi. As for [setuptools](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/), that's already installed into every venv by default.

Answer (score 0):

These two packages are not python packages and can not be installed using `pip`. You should install them using `apt`:

```
sudo apt install python3-usb python3-setuptools
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  That's a bit confusing as the Debian website says "This version of python-usb is written entirely in Python"  and both packages are required in the python code.  I appreciate that I can install using apt-get but I would rather install in the virtual environment.  If I can.